# Get form value from my payment module

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

My Magento version: 1.9
I already created a payment module, and it can post data to 3rd party
system. Now I want to display a select option (Yes and No) when click my
payment. Then I add this form:

```
<?php $_code=$this->getMethodCode() ?>
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $_code ?>" style="display:none;">
<li>
    <label for="<?php echo $_code ?>_period" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Installment plan') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select id="<?php echo $_code ?>_period" name="<?php echo $_code ?>_period" title="<?php echo $this->__('Installment plan') ?>" class="required-entry">
            <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $this->__('No') ?></option>
            <option value="1"><?php echo $this->__('Yes') ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</li>
```

After implementing this form, it will display on frontend.
And then I want to get the period value when I click place order.
So I add this code  on my **class extend Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract**

```
$payment = $this->getRequest()->getPost(payment);
```

But the $payment is empty. Do I miss something ?
Thanks for your help.